# Django Many2many field Attribute Error

Tags: python, django

I'm getting an unexpected error when trying to add data to a many2many field in a django model.  I'm not sure why I'm not getting the related data (payment_method)

For the models below

```
class PaymentMethod(models.Model):
    MONTHLY_DIRECT_DEBIT = 'MDD'
    CASH_OR_CHEQUE = 'CAC'
    QUARTERLY_DIRECT_DEBIT = 'QDD'
    PAYMENT_CHOICES = (
        (MONTHLY_DIRECT_DEBIT, 'Monthly Direct Debit'),
        (CASH_OR_CHEQUE, 'Cash or Cheque'),
        (QUARTERLY_DIRECT_DEBIT, 'Quarterly Direct Debit'),
    )
    unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Tariff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier)
    payment_method = models.ManyToManyField(PaymentMethod)
    region = models.ManyToManyField(Region)

        class Meta:
    unique_together = ('name', 'supplier')

class Supplier(models.Model):
unique_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

I am trying to add the payment method data to the tariff via:

```
supplier = Supplier.objects.get(unique_id=region.default_supplier.unique_id)
payment_method_instance = PaymentMethod.objects.get(unique_id=payment_method['id'])
tariff, created = Tariff.objects.get_or_create(name=tariff, supplier=supplier)
    if created:
        sys.stdout.write('Tariff {} not found for Supplier: {}\n'.format(tariff, supplier))
        tariff.payment_method.add(payment_method_instance)
```

when I try to access the tariff's payment method via the below I get the below error:

```
>>> tariff1.payment_method
Out[4]: <django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager at 0x11326c710>
>>> tariff.payment_method.unique_id
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 3066, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-a0370f309c95>", line 1, in <module>
    tariff.payment_method.unique_id
AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'unique_id'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `payment_method` field in `Tariff` model, is a M2M field, so it won't return an object, it will return a Set of objects. So, you can not access to `.unique_id` attr because it's not an `PaymentMethod` object. You could get the `unique_id` value for all the `PaymentMethod` objects related with your current `Tariff` object:

```
>>> tariff1.payment_method.all().values_list('unique_id', flat=True)
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense now you mention it returns a set. If I just need to pop any one out if there a way to do that concisely?

Comment: @Yunti Sure, you have a `QuerySet` there, you can use any model Manager's method, such as: `.get()`, `.filter()`